# Can not send form to PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I used some good ol' ajax for a submit function for a form I made. 
I made a little example with the same javascript I used. If the form was sent properly, then the user will not be alerted with anything. If the form was not sent, then the user will be alerted with "reee." In my case, the user is alerted with "reeeeee" as the form does not seem to be sent to the php script and I don't know why.

It goes a little likes this:

```
html

<form id = "theform" >
    <input name = "noodz" required>
</form>
```

```
js

const form = document.getElementById("theform");
form.addEventListener("submit", submitfunc);

function submitfunc(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    const thing = new XMLHttpRequest();
    thing.open("POST", "upload.inc.php");

    thing.upload.addEventListener("progress", e => {
        console.log(e);

    });

    thing.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (thing.readyState == 4 && thing.status == 200) {
            var message = thing.responseText;
            alert(message);
        }
    }

    thing.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
    thing.send(new FormData(form)); // <- where form is sent
}
```

```
php

<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['noodz'])){
        //form was sent

    } else {
        //form wasn't sent
        echo "reeeeeeeeeeeee"
    }
?>
```

Comment: If you're seeing _"reeeeeeeeeeeee"_ alerted, then your request **is** hitting the PHP script. What that means though is that `isset($_POST['noodz'])` is false. Check in your browser's _Network_ console to see what form data is being sent

Comment: You should insert code responsible for sending request to function `submitfunc`. Now you don't send any form data.

Comment: Yes, that's true. @coolpigeon2122, please format your code to be more readable.

Comment: Are you using any framework at the back-end which might catch the request before your PHP gets it?

Comment: @Teemu I am not using any fraimwork. Just pure old php.

Comment: @Phil I get something like: `0w
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="noodz"` Im not sure if im looking at the right thing.

Comment: How are you actually submitting the form? There's no submit button. If you're using JavaScript `.submit()`, the submit handler is never called, and the form will be submitted by the default GET method, that would explain why `$_POST['noodz']` isn't set.

Comment: @Teemu you can submit by hitting `Enter` with the text input focused ~ https://jsfiddle.net/qj3Lukp6/

Comment: @Phil Yes, I know, but then the submit handler is executed, and required attribute makes sure the input can't be empty. In case of a JS submit call, the handler is not executed. But, but ... That can't be the case, because then a new page would loaded, and the alert wouldn't occur.

Comment: Remove `thing.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")`. This header will be set automatically and will include the appropriate mime-boundary which is what you're missing

Comment: @Teemu Sorry I forgot to add a submit button in this example. The html isn't what I'm actually using. I deleted everything inside the form and added the noodz input and kept the javascript the same. This was so that I could keep it simple and to the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the line

```
thing.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")
```

and let XHR set the content-type value itself correctly and generate the correct MIME boundary (if needed - which it isn't, for your simple form).

Here's a demo https://jsfiddle.net/oxaqfbcd/ - if you look in the browser's Network tool you'll see the request correctly formed with the form data detected.

If you add that line of code back in and run it again, you can contrast the appearance of the request body section with when the line is not there, to see what effect it has.